# Multiple UploadFile in a page - SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I'm new to using SilverStripe and I need to know how to make it work with 4 different UploadFile elements in the same page. Images are not displayed in the Front-End.

[code](https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/0BwlTnvzV5xX8TmxLdERwU3cyR3M=w1486-h980-iv1)

[code2](https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/0BwlTnvzV5xX8cFhmQzRtQkx4dTA=w1486-h980-iv1)

[output](https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/0BwlTnvzV5xX8dmtYRmc2OFV3RHc=w1486-h703-iv1)

Comment: Here are the screenshots: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwlTnvzV5xX8VzRQS1NPY3Z3LVk?usp=sharing

Comment: Please upload screenshots using the tools provided, to the imgur.com host. And for code, please paste as text and use the formatting tools rather than taking a snapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you're basically trying to achieve this type of set-up: https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-data-relationships-has-many

In the example above if you were to call `Region` something like `Banner` instead it is basically the same thing, and would allow for more information to accompany a banner image. In the template you would replace `<% loop Children %>` with e.g.`<% loop Banners %>` (depending on what you name the relationship). This would allow a user to have more than four banners though, so if 4 is to be the maximum you would need some validation set up to check this before saving a new banner.

---

The reason your current setup shows no pictures is because of the <% loop Children %> command in the template. If you remove this, it should work in it's current form.

However I would advise against relying on the `$Title` to conditionally display a banner. Perhaps a single banner (instead of four) would be better? You can save a different banner per page in the CMS.